# What is the default value for $operator in condition()?

Tags: database

Basing on [`QueryConditionInterface::condition()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--query.inc/function/QueryConditionInterface::condition/7), the default value for `$operation` is `NULL`, while [Conditional clauses](http://drupal.org/node/310086) says its default value is `'='`.

What is the default value? Does it change basing on the datatype of `$value`, for example it's `'IN' for array and` '='` for integers and strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QueryConditionInterface is just that, an interface. The actual class used is [DatabaseCondition](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--query.inc/class/DatabaseCondition/7).

In [DatabaseCondition:condition()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--query.inc/function/DatabaseCondition%3A%3Acondition/7), it does set the default operator:

```
if (!isset($operator)) {
  if (is_array($value)) {
    $operator = 'IN';
  }
  elseif (!isset($value)) {
    $operator = 'IS NULL';
  }
  else {
    $operator = '=';
  }
}
```