# What is the equivalent of "WHERE nid IN :nids AND (col1 = 1 OR col2 = 1)" with the SelectQuery class?

Tags: database

How do you build a query with a `WHERE` clause like the following one, with a SelectQuery object?

```
WHERE nid IN :nids AND (col1 = 1 OR col2 = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a `SelectQuery` object, you use code similar to the following one.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array(/* The fields you need to obtain */))
  ->condition('n.nid', $array_containing_the_ids)
  ->condition(
    db_or()->condition('n.col1', 1)->condition('n.col2', 1)
  );
```

For that type of query, if you don't need to allow other modules to alter the query being executed, which is possible for the other modules with [hook_query_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7), you can use [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7). In this case, the code is similar to the following one.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT /* The fields you need to obtain */ WHERE nid IN :nids AND (col1 = 1 OR col2 = 1", array(':nids' => $array_containing_the_ids));
```

With the object returned from `db_select()`, the conditions you add with `$query->condition()` are ANDed together; that is because the constructor of the `SelectQuery` class contains the following code.

```
  $this->where = new DatabaseCondition('AND');
  $this->having = new DatabaseCondition('AND');
```

If you need to OR two conditions, you need to execute code similar to the following one.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array(/* The fields you need to obtain */))
  ->condition(
    db_or()->condition('n.col1', 1)->condition('n.col2', 1)
  );
```

If the value you pass to `condition()` is an array, the method assumes you are using the `IN` operator; there is no need to make it explicit, in the same way the `=` is implicit for integer and string values. See [What is the default value for $operator in condition()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/what-is-the-default-value-for-operator-in-condition)

As side note, when querying entities, such as nodes, and users, you can also use the `EntityFieldQuery` class. As far as I can understand, with the `EntityFieldQuery` class you cannot build a query to obtain entities where, for example, property A is equal to X, or property B is equal to Y, and property C is equal to Z.